# Link from 3rd level to 1st level on multi-level menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, multi-level

I’ve been working with this Codrops multi-level responsive menu.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

When you go deep in that menu, it creates back-link to previous level on top of the menu. What I’m trying to create is straight back-link to first level if you go 3rd level or deeper. Also I’d like to keep back-link that goes only one step backwards.

I created a Codepen where you can also see the menu working.

http://codepen.io/morteymor/pen/zvxqVJ

```
Code
```

[image: Additional back button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you want to do.

---

Created VARs:

```
_config : function() {
    this.open = false;
    this.$trigger = this.$el.children( '.dl-trigger' );
    this.$menu = this.$el.children( 'ul.dl-menu' );
    this.$menuitems = this.$menu.find( 'li:not(.dl-back)' );
    this.$el.find( 'ul.dl-submenu' ).prepend( '<li class="dl-back"><a href="#">back</a></li>' );
    this.$back = this.$menu.find( 'li.dl-back' );

    //ADDED
    this.$el.find('ul.dl-submenu ul.dl-submenu').prepend('<li class="dl-back-top"><a href="#">Back to first level</a></li>');
    this.$backTop = this.$menu.find('li.dl-back-top');
},
```

- Add a "Back to first level" button for none first level submenu's
- And create the $backTop variable for a later use

---

```
this.$backTop.on('click.dlmenu', function(event) {

   var $this = $( this ),
        $submenu = $this.parents( 'ul.dl-submenu:first' ),
        $item = $submenu.parent(),

        $flyin = $submenu.clone().insertAfter( self.$menu );

    //ADDED
    self._resetMenu();

    var onAnimationEndFn = function() {

        self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
        $flyin.remove();

    };

    setTimeout( function() {
        $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
        self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
        if( self.supportAnimations ) {
            self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
        }
        else {
            onAnimationEndFn.call();
        }

        $item.removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );

        var $subview = $this.parents( '.dl-subview:first' );
        if( $subview.is( 'li' ) ) {
            $subview.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );
        }
        $subview.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
    } );

    return false;

});
```

- Duplicated click event from $back button for previously created button ($backTop) and add `self._resetMenu();` to reset the menu on click "Back to first"

---

Finally just need to create class's for new button:

```
.dl-menuwrapper li.dl-back-top > a {
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.dl-menuwrapper li.dl-back-top:after{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  speak: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "<<";
  font-family: "arial";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

---

> [Updated CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQbGwY)

Comment: Sorry for slow response. This looks very promising. I’ll try this today and will let you know how it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Got implemented it and only few tweaks and it supports older browser too. Huge thanks!